# Android API 31 (Version 12) only 64 bit version?

Tags: android, 64-bit, android-12

App that I am currently working on uses a library that **doesn't work on 64 bit version**.

In a link below there is info only about 64bit version:

Android 12 emulator system images for mobile devices (**64-bit only**, see release notes)
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/overview#preview_tools

Has something changed and google will offer only 64-bit versions of emulator? Or when stable version (non-preview) comes out there will be also 32-bit version?

Comment: You need to make it work for the 64 bit as well, or you will find an issue publishing it on Google Play

Answer (score 0):

Google has previously announced that they are dropping support in Google Play for 32 bit architectures

[This guide](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit) may help if you need direction in transitioning from 32 to 64 bit.

You mention you are using a 3rd party library that doesn't work in 64bit. You are in a pickle. If you can't make it work you will need another solution.

Google first announced the intention to move to 64bit in 2017 and as of August 1, 2019 all 32-bit apps had to have a 64-bit version too.